# Access variable values using name of variable in string, R

Tags: arrays, r, string, list

### Intro

A data set has a large number of `age.year` variables: `age.1990, age.1991, etc.` I have an array of string values of `length(age.years)` representing those variables such that `age.years[1]` returns `"age.1990"`, etc.

### Need

I want to search the `age.year` variables for each record to find the value, `60`. Ultimately, if `age.1991[1]` equals 60, then a new variable `Y.60[1]` will take the value `Y.1991[1]`.

### Question

How do I use strings from arrays as variable names to avoid coding each `var.year` variable by hand? `Get()` does not seem to work.

```
# EXAMPLE CODE
big.data= data.frame(ID= c(1,2), age.1990= c(60, NA), 
  age.1991= c(61, 60), age.1992= c(62, 61), Y.1990= c(100, 120), 
  Y.1991= c(NA, 125), Y.1992= c(115, 130), Y.60= c(NA, NA) )

big.data
#   ID age.1990 age.1991 age.1992 Y.1990 Y.1991 Y.1992 Y.60
# 1  1       60       61       62    100     NA    115   NA
# 2  2       NA       60       61    120    125    130   NA 

age.years = names(big.data)[2:4]
Y.years = names(big.data)[5:7]
age.years[1]= paste0("big.data$", age.years[1])
age.years[1]
# [1] "big.data$age.1990"
summary(age.years[1])
# Length     Class      Mode 
#    1 character character 
summary(get(age.years[1]))
# Error in get(age.years[1]) : object 'big.data$age.1990' not found
# Why not found??
```

Comment: Try `big.data[[age.years[1]]]`. The double brackets find a single column by name or number.

Comment: Just curious, I added your edit with due credit and you removed the answer marker. Do you still need help with the question? Or maybe the edits cancel it out? Can't say I'm not new to SO yet, so I'm being curious.

Comment: For future reference. If the issue is indeed solved, then the benefit of marking it so is that it doesn't appear in the "unanswered questions" section anymore which in case of R is rather crowded anyway. But do find your own way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use paste in brackets to access the column as you would otherwise do with $.

```
big.data[paste0(age.years[1])]
```

Additionally, you can use just the numbers to access the columns like this.

```
years <- c(1990:1992)
big.data[paste0("age.",years[1])]
```

And the loop will work like this.

```
for (iy in 1:length(years)){
  big.data$Y.60 <- NA
  big.data$Y.60  <- ifelse(big.data[paste0("age.",years[iy])] == 60,     +
     paste0("Y.",years[iy]),big.data$Y.60 ) 
 }
```

If I understood your purpose correctly.

**Update:**

Or an alternative answer from the author @jtd with brackets instead of paste.

```
for (iy in 1:length(age.years)) {
   big.data$Y = ifelse(big.data[[age.years[iy]]] == 60,
              big.data[[Y.years[iy]]],
              big.data$Y
              )
}
```