# How to access list in a list by character name in a loop?

Tags: r, list

I have a list X of three elements. Each element X[[i]] is a list of two – X1 and X2.

I want to construct a list X_new which would be a list of two elements X1 and X2, each element X_new[[i]] is a list of three.

This works perfectly fine:

```
X_new <- vector(mode = "list", length = 2)
X_new[[1]] <- lapply(X, function(x) x$X1)
X_new[[2]] <- lapply(X, function(x) x$X2)
```

But what if instead of 2 I have *n*? I tried this

```
X_new <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
ind <- names(X[[1]])
for (i in 1:n) {
   X[[i]]  <- lapply(X, function(x) x$ind[i])
}
```

but it doesn't work, I just get null lists.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `transpose` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
X_new <- transpose(X)
```

-output

```
X_new
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] "a"

#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] "a"


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] "b"

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] "b"

#[[2]][[3]]
#[1] "b"
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I'd still like to know if there's a way to access the element of the list by specifying the name in a loop but your solution is great for now.

Comment: I didn't mark this as an answer because it's not :) I still would like to know how I can access list elements by character names

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589947/access-variable-values-using-name-of-variable-in-string-r) for an answer. In short, you can use *paste* inside the [[]] list brackets.